# Are questions related to translation about Islamic books on topic?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/) on Islam meta SE brings about the topic of Islamic references in English language. It is always a challenge to find translations of some the required references. However, are questions — like this [one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/) — on Islam SE asking for a translation of an Islamic book considered on topic?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the general question, I see no reason why questions *related to* translations of Islamic books shouldn't be on-topic. Especially as an English-language site where many users are not fluent in Arabic, being able to know and ask about the sources that are actually available in English (or whatever native language you prefer) is important in the study of Islam.

For example, asking about whether a particular translation [is well-regarded](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/22) is probably fine, as is asking if a particular passage is accurately translated if there's some notable reason for doubt. Even asking about [the credentials of the translator](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1064/22), I see no problem with.

However, the [particular question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7372/22) you bring up is potentially problematic because it's not asking *about* a translation, it's asking *for* a translation. In other words, it basically presents as a [book recommendation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/22) question, which can be tricky to work with under the limitations of the Stack Exchange model.

Even if it's readily answerable now (I don't know the particulars about the book or the available translations to really know), answers are expected to be useful for future visitors as well as the questioner: As new books (including new translations of existing books) come out over time, such answers will just get more and more obsolete (and therefore more and more useless) unless it's somehow kept fresh.

Answer (score 1):

We have many questions about literature here already and we also have a tag [books](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books).
Where you might find posts like for example:
[Sources of Fiqh from Madhabs](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38318/sources-of-fiqh-from-madhabs)
[Does the book "Reliance of the Traveller" play a significant role in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37803/does-the-book-reliance-of-the-traveller-play-a-significant-role-in-Islam)
[Are there any surviving manuscript of books written by the scholars listed below?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38025/are-there-any-surviving-manuscript-of-books-written-by-the-scholars-listed-below)
[Are there any books written by female scholars?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37757/are-there-any-books-written-by-female-scholars)
...

I think most of them are at least focused and answerable questions, so from this point of view they perfectly fit here on SE. Which also is the case for translations of known books as the one quoted in your post.

Of course it might be better to create a well phrased meta-post on that topic as "a collective thread or post" and refer to it (maybe mine which you linked in your post is not really a good choice or at least needs some elaboration or re-phrasing).

But as said I see no harm in those questions, they might not be of general benefit at firsr sight, but many people could drop in later and have the same question in mind.